# What format should I obey when I pass string into kernel_sendmsg?

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel

Recently, I'm modifying some socket program in kernel space. Following is basic server sending function:

```cpp
static int http_server_send(struct socket *sock, const char *buf, size_t size)
{
    struct msghdr msg = {.msg_name = NULL,
                         .msg_namelen = 0,
                         .msg_control = NULL,
                         .msg_controllen = 0,
                         .msg_flags = 0};
    int done = 0;
    while (done < size) {
        struct kvec iov = {
            .iov_base = (void *) ((char *) buf + done),
            .iov_len = size - done,
        };
        int length = kernel_sendmsg(sock, &msg, &iov, 1, iov.iov_len);
        if (length < 0) {
            pr_err("write error: %d\n", length);
            break;
        }
        done += length;
    }
    return done;
}
```

I found `buf` or `iov_base` follow some specific format when it was passed, format is like following which define as macro ( CRLF is define as "\r\n" ):

```
    ""                                                        \
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" CRLF "Server: " KBUILD_MODNAME CRLF     \
    "Content-Type: text/plain" CRLF "Content-Length: %d" CRLF \
    "Connection: Close" CRLF CRLF "%s" CRLF
```

Some of above format seems can't be changed (Changed will fail to send message), maybe this is kind of protocol. My question is are there any document or reference can I find the regulation of these format?

Comment: No, `kernel_sendmsg` is abstraction-less, you can send anything. You are asking for http protocol specification? Implementing http server in kernel space looks like a really, really bad idea.

Comment: I am not sure this macro is spec. If it does, I want to know some key word to find this stuff. Also, why implement server in kernel space is bad idea?

Comment: I do not understand. `I am not sure this macro is spec` A "macro" (tokens of characters as defined by C standard) can't be a "spec"-ification (detailed description of how something should be done). `I want to know some key word to find this stuff` - what "stuff"? What do you want to find? `why implement server in kernel space is bad idea?` because it's not a device driver, it's not a scheduler, it's not a resource management, it's very broadly outside of what an operating system kernel should be doing. A http service is clearly not an interaction between hardware and software - it's a service.

Comment: I think that macro is following some format(maybe spec) because when I tried to change part of it. Sever can't send anymore. e.g. change `HTTP` into `HTP`. As a result, I wondering where can I find these format